# How to get the length of the column #3? Python

Tags: python, indexing, content-length

I'm super new to this, I honestly don't understand that much. Can someone help me to create a code to get the sum of column # 3, sorry if this is too silly, hope you can help me. Thanks

It's a tab file.

#Open file (must be a .tab file)

`file = open("chromosome_length.tab")`

#According to the READ ME file, chromosome 17 is the mitochondrial chromosome.

##Print line 17

```
lines_to_print = [16]

for index, line in enumerate(file):
  if ( index in lines_to_print):
    print("Mitochondrial chromosome:")
    print(line)
```

#How long are the chromosome?

```
with open("chromosome_length.tab") as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')

values = [int(i.split()[2]) for i in lines]
print(sum(values))
```

#Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vc/Downloads/assig.py", line 19, in <module>
    values = [int(i.split()[2]) for i in lines]
  File "/Users/vc/Downloads/assig.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    values = [int(i.split()[2]) for i in lines]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

FILE:

```
3   NC_001135   316620
4   NC_001136   1531933
5   NC_001137   576874
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Avoid posting your code, output, or errors in images, post it in a text format instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
with open('chromosome_length.tab') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')

values = [int(i.split()[2]) for i in lines if i]
print(sum(values))
```

**Explanation:**

Opening the file `chromosome_length.tab` in reading mode, reading all the text, splitting the text by new line (`\n`)
At this point, we have something like this in our `lines` list:

```
[
    "1 NC1234 1234",
    "2 NC4321 5678",
    ...
]
```

In order to get the 3rd column of each line, we iterate through each line in `lines`, split the line by space, so we have `["1", "NC1234", "1234"]`, get the 3rd column by `[2]` and convert it to `int`.

So, we have all the values in our `values` list: `[1234, 5678, ...]`

In the end, we use the built-in function `sum()` to sum the values in the `values` list and print them

---

*UPD:* Problem was in the empty string `''` at the end of the list. Adding filter `if i` for our `inline for` loop solved this issue.

---

*Hope that helps :)*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I'm sorry that I don't post it in the right format. 

I did what you suggested, but I get an error. I edited my question.

Comment: Seems like they are separated by tabs instead of space, try `int(i.split("\t")[2]`. If it will not work, then try uploading your tab file to any sharing service and sharing the link here.

Comment: Ok, this was an empty string issue, there was a new empty line at the end of the file. I've updated the answer. If it solves your problem don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as an 'Accepted Answer')

Comment: Amazing! Now it did work, thank you so much for your help, I hope this can be of use to others. I was also able to learn something, thank you very much.